# Displaying Panoramio thumbnail layer on Google Maps using REST

Tags: google-maps, panoramio

I'm trying to display a layer of thumbnail images on my Google Map via Panoramio. The Panoramio is RESTful and its homepage states a simple GET request must be submitted on the API url.

I don't have much experience with REST and have tried just to get the API to respond with text before I can process the JSON that is supposed to result from the call. I don't have much experience with AJAX, could smeone point me in the right direction? Here is my pertinent code thus far:

```
**HTML**
<div class="backdiv-pix"></div>

**JS**
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var thumbUrl = "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=20&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&size=medium&mapfilter=true"
xmlhttp.open("GET", thumbUrl, true)
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById('backdiv-pix').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

My browser is throwing the following error:

*Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*

Some guidance would be much appreciated.

MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no div with `id="backdiv-pix"` in your code.  Either change:

```
<div class="backdiv-pix"></div>
```

To:

```
<div id="backdiv-pix"></div>
```

Or use `document.getElmentByClassName('backdiv-pix')[0].innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText`

However, once you fix that typo, you will need to deal with this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=20&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&size=medium&mapfilter=true. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yo7m9xeb/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var thumbUrl = "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=20&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&size=medium&mapfilter=true&callback=?"
$.getJSON(thumbUrl, function(data) {
  document.getElementById('backdiv-pix').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="backdiv-pix"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch geocodezip for your input. I have two further questions if you are willing to give me a hand:
1 - Running this script I am not getting any error messages but not seeing the raw JSON data within my div, is there something I am missing? 2 -My goal is to use the JSON response to show Panoramio photos on my Google Map as thumbnails. I have spent several days tryng to find a tutorial on how to do this but the search is stymied by the existence and subsequent deprecation of the google map API's embedded panoramio layer. If you could refer me or assist that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do see the data and can see that it functions correctly. I guess my strategy was to display raw JSON on my webpage to prove a connection to the Panoramio API, and then process the JSON to display georeferenced thumbnail photos in my Google Map.